# after update to angular2 beta.1, the router no longer works. It did in beta.0

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

My test page did routing with beta.0, but not with beta.1. Atom-typscript shows no errors and the Console has no errors when the page loads, but the anchor choices do not have the link color - they have text color. When the anchors are clicked, this Console error appears.

```
ERROR CONTEXT: angular2.min.js:17:5927

13:21:22.030 Object { element: <a>, componentElement: <residence-app>, context: Object, locals: Object, injector: Object } angular2.min.js:17:5927

13:21:22.038 Error: EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.directive_0_0.onClick is not a function
```

Relevant code is:

**app.ts**  (a boot.ts file does the bootstrap for all components)

```
//various imports
@Component({
  selector: 'residence-app',
  templateUrl: "angular2-oPost/src/components/navigation/headerFooter.html",
  styleUrls: [ "angular2-oPost/src/commonStyles/headerFooter.css" ],
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Home, PostApartment4Rent ]
@RouteConfig( [
  new Route({ path: "/home", name: "Home", component: Home, useAsDefault: true }),
  new Route({ path: "/postApartment4Rent ",  name: "PostApartment4Rent", component: PostApartment4Rent })
] )
export class HeaderFooter { }
```

**headerFooter.html**

```
<header>
<!-- several divs-->
<a [routerLink]="['/Home']">Home</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/PostApartment4Rent']">Rent Apartment in hF</a>
</header> 
<div class="partialPage">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<footer>
  <!-- several divs-->
</footer>
```

**home.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector : "home",
  styleUrls: [ "angular2-oPost/src/commonStyles/headerFooter.css" ],
  templateUrl: "angular2-oPost/src/components/navigation/home.html",
  directives: [ RouterLink ]
})
export class Home { }
```

**postApartment4Rent.ts** - is the same as home.ts, except for the selector in the @Component and the class statement

What's the fix? The release notes do not mention a breaking change for router.

Comment: Go back to Beta.0 and wait for better release.

Comment: As @VladoTesanovic mentioned you can go back to beta.0 since there are issues with minified bundles in beta.1. So you can downgrade or use the `dev` bundles (not minified)

Comment: @Eric Martinez thanks colleague :)

Comment: I tried - bundles/angular2.dev.js - and get the same problem. I'll go back to beta.0  Thanks, at least I know my code is OK.

Comment: @Eric Martinez  I have upgraded to beta.6 and the related software that it needs. It still will not route between pages.  When I put useAsDefault true in either route statement, I get that page on load. So some kind of routing occurs. But when routing between pages, I get the Console error - TypeError: this.directive_0_0.onClick is not a function. My routerLink code is as shown above.  Is the problem me, or continuing problems in beta code?

Comment: There are still issues with minification, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6678

Comment: @EricMartinez With beta.7, I have strange routing behavior.  With useAsDefault: true on the second page, the links show as clickable and when I click on one, it routes back to the home page. I can use the back and forward buttons to go between the 2 pages. The same links on the home page do not show as clickable, and when I click on them I get the 'not a function' error I mentioned above. With useAsDefault: true on the home page route statement, home loads but no routing occurs via buttons or links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is still present in angular2.beta.7. It's caused by the same bug you can find here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6380

The problem is caused by the minification of your app with webpack (using UglifyJS), you can solve this bug temporary by removing something which looks like the following code in webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'bundle.js'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
],
```

The problem is that your app won't be production ready because your bundle.js will be too fat, but you'll be able to develop your app ;)

I checked if the problem didn't come from the UglifyJS configuration, but no I confirm that it's a problem with Angular2.

If I find a way to fix that i'll come back to help you, good luck ;)